# Why is "Recruit" not working for Sweet's mission "Los Sepulcros" in GTA: San Andreas on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, backwards-compatibility, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I am playing *GTA: San Andreas* on a Windows 10 environment and have reached the mission "Los Sepulcros". However, I can't complete the mission because I have to use the "recruit" feature to start. The in-game tutorials tell me to aim at a gang member (using rmb) and press G to Recruit but it doesn't work. Is this something to do with Windows OS compatibility? I ask this because when I first downloaded GTA: SA, I had my mouse working improperly (I solved it by downloading the application extension "dinput8.dll").

There is a similar problem faced by someone else as well: [Magnet not working in Zero's mission "New Model Army" in GTA: San Andreas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/316081/254067)

I have tried enabling the frame limiter as suggested in an answer to the above question, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The link is in the comment above, but I've proofread the question and added the link in the question as well. Let me know if it makes sense now

Comment: It makes sense now.  Have you tried the solution in the answer to the other question? (The one about the frame limiter.)

Comment: It asks us to move this discussion to chat. The answer is yes, I have tried that (I deliberately made this comment long so it lets me post; just "yes" was too short)

Comment: @galacticninja thanks for proofreading, but I could use some real help here. Are you going to answer?

Comment: @ShubhRoy Can you confirm that you have at least a few points of [Respect](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Respect)? And can you try changing the key from 'G' in options? If you're pushing other keys nearby it's possible you're affected by [key ghosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_jamming_and_ghosting). You can use [this tool](https://drakeirving.github.io/MultiKeyDisplay/) to test your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Robotnik, but I think I have enough points of respect and there is no ghosting problem either. I figured out the problem and I appreciate your help. I'll just post the answer.

Comment: @ShubhRoy No problem. Glad to hear you figured it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this problem ever occurs to anyone else, just go Options > Controller Setup > Redefine Controls > Foot controls
You'll see this:[image: Controls]

Like I said, to recruit I had to aim at a gang member and press G. If you look at the image, you can see there are two alternate controls for aiming (del and capslock). When I use del to aim rather than rmb, it works. But when I use rmb, I can aim, but nothing happens when I press G.

What you can take away from this is if a particular control doesn't work the way expected, try the alternate controls.